# Updating values in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm munging some time series data that was stored poorly.

There is a column which I have made the index that has time stamps that are mostly every 15 minutes, but some are shorter. There are also `start_sec` and  `end_sec` columns that give what part of the interval the row is for.

The problem is that the data creator assumed the time intervals are all 15 minutes long so all of the `start_sec` `end_sec` values run 0 to 900 (psuedo-seconds) regardless of actual interval length. I would like to combine these columns into start time (index) and length in actual seconds.

My very kludgy solution to rescale things was to generate a list of time stamps for the short intervals and put everything in a for loop

```
for i in short_intervals:
    scale = float(df[ (df.index == i) ].delta.max()) / 60. / 15.
    df[ (df.index == i) ].start_sec = df[(df.index == i)].start_sec * scale
    df[ (df.index == i) ].end_sec = df[(df.index == i)].end_sec * scale
```

where
`df.index == i` selects the relevant set of rows for given time stamp
`df.delta.max()` has the actual length of the interval in minutes (because of how things are stored)
`scale` gives the value that I want to scale my psuedo-seconds by to get actual seconds.

All of that works fine, and I thought I was done, but

```
df[ (df.index == i) ].start_sec = df[(df.index == i)].start_sec * scale
```

doesn't actually update the DataFrame, df is exactly the same after the loop as before hand.

Comment: if you print `scale` what is it? did you try using a different field name (`scaled_start`) to see if it gets assigned the original value?

Comment: The scale values are what they should be (things like .3333, .4, .9333). I tried creating another column before the loop and assigning to that in the same way, but it doesn't update either. I was wondering if it was a type conversion error and scale was being rounded to 1, but `start_sec` has type float64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using your `df.index` syntax, try this:

```
df.start_sec[i] = df.start_sec[i] * scale
df.end_sec[i] = df.end_sec[i] * scale
```

Or even:

```
df.start_sec[i] *= scale
df.end_sec[i] *= scale
```

In my tests, the frame is **not** assigning any values with this syntax:

```
df[(df.index==i)].start_sec = 25
```

Someone else could probably explain why, but it probably has to do with this:

```
>>> type(df.A[i])
<type 'numpy.int64'>
>>> type(df[(df.index==i)].A)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Comment: perfect! I'm having trouble not thinking of everything as arrays.

Comment: see here for an explanation of why chained assignment doesn't work: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy, in 0.13 what the OP was doing would show a warning